# Get the pasted list of values from TextArea AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to get the pasted list of Ids in the controller.js so that I can pass the list of Ids to an API

what I am trying :

HTML

```
<textarea rows="3" placeholder="copy/paste here..." ng-model="content" ng-paste="pasteFunction($event)" style="margin: 0px; width: 249px; height: 172px;"></textarea>
```

controller.js

```
$scope.pasteFunction = function (e) {
                $scope.pasted = e.clipboardData.getData('text').split(" ").map(Number);
                alert($scope.pasted);
            }
```

however, I am not getting the values. How to retrieve the list of pasted data (assume 100 Ids) from the textarea and again resetting the textarea for the next paste

Answer (score 1):

You can use (change) event in angular for getting the value. No need to get value from clipboard. Directly access it from the event itself(event.target.value).

```
 <textarea
  rows="3"
  placeholder="copy/paste here..."
  (change)="handleValue($event)"
  style="margin: 0px; width: 249px; height: 172px;">
 </textarea>


handleValue($event) {
   console.log($event.target.value.split(" ").map(Number));
   var pasted = $event.target.value.split(" ").map(Number);
   //To reset textarea value for next data entering
   $event.target.value = "";
   alert(pasted);
}
```

[For Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/get-data-from-textarea-el?file=src/app/hello.component.ts)

Comment: thanks for the answer, having limited knowledge on angular, is it applicable for angularJS as well?